# Why do I need to install -devel packages?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum

I wonder why many times when I install package with `yum` I need to install `package-devel.i386` rather than `package.i386`. What is the difference between them?

Comment: In your example `package` would contain files needed to run programs that use the library. `package-devel` would contain files needed to compile programs that use the library.

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific. There may be valid reasons beyond "to build stuff", but we can't tell you with only the little information you've provided.

Answer (score 8):

Normally a package will contain binaries, libraries, and other resources, so that programs linked against those libraries can run.

But when you need to build a package, header files are required normally, in this case, you install theose -devel packages to supply the desired header file.

Try to learn more about C/C++ build mechanism to help you understand this better.