# RHEL 9 stuck trying to compile LXapearance. gtk +- 2 not found 2.12.0 installed (i think)

Tags: rhel, compiling, gtk

hello so my configure file yields me the following result.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.12.0 gthread-2.0) were not met:

Package 'gtk+-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

I assume that i need to  set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I dont know however what values i need to give these.

Can annyone be so kind to assist me ?

Comment: You probably need the corresponding *development package* (gtk2-devel?) - see also [Why do I need to install -devel packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49331/why-do-i-need-to-install-devel-packages)

Comment: there is no gtk2-devel package for rhel9  also no 3 or 4.
I`m a bit hesitand to just ad a random rpm.

Comment: Hmm it does exist i gues i was just being dumb/blind,
its called gtk2-devel